# UIButton highlight state only works from .normal -> .selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Using IB I've assigned images to a button's .normal, .highlighted, and .selected states.  When pressing the button during a .normal->.selected transition (`someButton.isSelected = true`) the .highlighted image is correctly presented while touched, however when setting `someButton.isSelected = false` to return to .normal I see the standard quick-fade transition instead of my .highlighted image.  I saw in [this SO post from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878555/highlighted-state-for-uibutton-doesnt-come-when-going-from-selected-to-normal-s) a similar problem, however I'm wondering if the solution is still applicable in Swift 4 as I'm not quite understanding it.  My goal is to have the "glowing" image presented at each button touch. Thanks!

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
@IBAction func someButtonArray(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "TRANSITION_Pad-10.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "INITIAL_Pad-13.png"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }, completion: nil)
        sender.isSelected = false
} else if sender.isSelected != true {
    sender.isSelected = true
    for buttons in 0...11 where buttons != (sender.tag) {
        someButtonArray[buttons].isSelected = false
    }
  }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: can you upload any gifs ?

Comment: @karthik gif added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this in the view did Load

```
        yourButtonObj.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
```

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately it creates the same issue.

Comment: Also try :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110700/why-are-my-uisegmentcontrol-segments-highlighting-in-ios-8-when-i-have-set-backg/34098670#34098670

Comment: I followed the link and ended up successful trying this in my code: `...for: UIControl.State(rawValue: UIControl.State.selected.rawValue | UIControl.State.highlighted.rawValue))...` .  I'm still trying to figure out exactly why that worked, but I learned more about the how a button can be in a state of both selected and highlighted at the same time (which was the main issue).  Thanks! I haven't seen much documentation about that.

Comment: I thing the issue was related to segmentation 
 So would you mind marking my answer or upvoting it please

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional line like below:

```
[self.allTempoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.allTempoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.allTempoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.allTempoButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```